# Turn on LED with the opening of a switch

Tags: switches, npn

Hi I’d like a circuit that turns on an LED when the switch opens. I’ve made this so far, but it’s drawing too much current in the “off mode” that it will just drain my battery. Any ideas? I’ve seen one with a mosfet, but I don’t have one of those, just transistors or a 555?
[image]

Comment: I tried wiring that up, but couldn’t get it so that it wouldn’t create a short when button is closed

Comment: Your schematic is a short circuit switch across battery or PS  (hmmmm) and a tad hard to read (not enuf pixels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work.  Tune R1 for LED on current.  Tune R2 for your specific transistor, to get it into saturation.

**Update:** To save battery current, you can run the transistor not in saturation mode (make R2 even bigger).  But you won't get good repeatability from circuit to circuit as the gain of transistors can vary wildly from part to part.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwN0GC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Works great, thanks!

Comment: Rob .. think about switches as low side.and transistors invert but with low side drive. open switch-NC turns on

Comment: @RobAnderson  Don't forget to mark an accepted answer.  :)